# Set Attr Required when a checkbox for that field is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some looping rows which each row has a check box. And in each row there is a dropdown list which I want it to be set as `required` when the checkbox in the row is selected.

```
MARK       NAME                   QUANTITY         
---------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName1        Choose => 1,2,3,4,5    
---------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName2        Choose => 1,2,3,4,5    
---------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName3        Choose => 1,2,3,4,5    
---------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName4        Choose => 1,2,3,4,5  
---------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName5        Choose => 1,2,3,4,5   
---------------------------------------------------
                                   [SUBMIT]
```

(here `[]` is a Check-Box, and `Choose =>` is a dropdown selection)

```
                echo'   <tr>
                        <td><input name="checkbox[]"  type="checkbox"  value="'.$i++.'" /></td>
                        <td><input name="items[]"     type="text"      value="'.$obj->items.'"></td>

                echo'   <td><select name="esquantity[]" required >
                            <option value="" >Choose Quantity</option>';
                              for ($q=1; $q <= $obj->quantity; $q++) {                                
                     echo'  <option value="'.$q.'"> '.$q.' </option>'; }
                     echo'  </select></td>';
                echo'</tr>';                                
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                    </table>


        <?php

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $i) { 

                            $product_name=$_POST['items'][$i];
                            $product_quan=$_POST['esquantity'][$i];


                mysql_query("INSERT INTO estockClaims (items, 
                                                       esquantity)
                                            VALUES    ('$product_name',  
                                                       '$product_quan')");
                }
            }
        ?>
```

The problem is when I check only two checkboxes and I submit them, it asks me to select all the dropdown list in the quantity column.

**Sketch of Jquery**

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
               $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e)){
        //          var thisCheckbox = $(this);
                    var thisCheckbox = $('select[name="esquantity"]');
                    var thisRow = thisCheckbox.closest('tr');
                     if($(this.is(':checked')) {

                     }
                        .attr('required'));
                }
            }       
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm not good with `php`, but I do not see anywhere that you check for the checkboxes and set the specific quantity dropdown as `required`. The only thing I see is that for each added object, you set the quantity field as `required`.

Comment: Yes that is the matter here. What I want is to make it required if only it is checked. Any idea?

Comment: Instead I am not too good in Jquery. As far as I know I can do this with set an attribute of required when it is checked. Probably you may help me in the jquery script for this?

Comment: It was better if you could add a http://Jsfiddle.net example for me to edit

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/n13wbran/

Comment: @RaeenHashemi Please have a look at my update question where I added jquery script which has not finished yet/.

Comment: Sry for the delay, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you didn't forget tags: `<table><form>` and close the input tags also `<input ... />`

So for your code you can try this (PHP/HTML part):

```
$i++;
echo'   <tr>
        <td><input name="checkbox['.$i.']"  type="checkbox"  value="'.$i.'"  id="chb'.$i.'" onchange="enableList(this);" /></td>
        <td><input name="items['.$i.']"     type="text"      value="'.$obj->items.'" /></td>';

echo'   <td><select name="esquantity['.$i.']" id="select'.$i.'" disabled onchange="checkSelect(this)">
            <option value="" >Choose Quantity</option>';
              for ($q=1; $q <= $obj->quantity; $q++) {                                
     echo'  <option value="'.$q.'"> '.$q.' </option>'; }
     echo'  </select></td>';
echo'</tr>';
```

Then I've noticed in the **SUBMIT** part:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $i) { 
    $product_name=$_POST['items'][$key];
    $product_quan=$_POST['esquantity'][$key];
    //more code
  }
}
```

And the Javascript part:

```
function enableList(element) {
    var select = document.getElementById("select"+element.id.substring(element.id.length-1));

    if(element.checked === true){
        select.disabled = false;
        checkSelect(select);
    }else{
        select.disabled = true;
        select.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

function checkSelect(element){
    if(!validate_select(element)){
        element.setCustomValidity("Choose an option");
    }else{
        element.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}

function validate_select(select){
    if(select.selectedIndex === 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDITED:** In order to achieve the new purpose (submit only if at least one input is checked):

Add to the checkbox one class as an identifier: `class="chb_group"` (so you don't have to worry about other checkboxes)... and an id for the submit button maybe: `id="btn_submit"` and `disabled` by default

So you add:

```
function enableSubmit(){
    if (document.querySelector('.chb_group:checked')) {
        document.getElementById('btn_submit').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('btn_submit').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

And call it in:

```
function enableList(element) {
    var select = document.getElementById("select"+element.id.substring(element.id.length-1));
    enableSubmit();
    .....
}
```

**NOTE:** This code will work only in "modern" browsers because of some functions and properties like: `setCustomValidity` and `querySelector`

Comment: It only disable the quantity dropdown list. And the required function doesn't work. Help

Comment: Setting `required` for a select is not really useful that's why I choose disabled/enabled

Comment: But the code you gave doesn't achieve anything. It is only disable it.

Comment: When it is checked ,the dropdown is still disable.Can you please revise the  code above?

Comment: Are you sure? I've tried it. In which browser it brings problem?

Comment: Yes, it is still disable even when the checkbox has been checked.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? (I've tried it at Firefox 33.1 and Chrome 38.0)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in `$i++` --> `$i` in a couple of inputs, I've edited my answer

Comment: :) Can you help me again how to  only show the submit button if only there is one of the checkbox button is checked. Or something like that.

Comment: Because it now can be submited when there is no checkbox is checked.

Comment: I've added a function for that purpose... all this code would work in "modern" browsers

Comment: Man, I found a problem with this code. In the first row, say if I have three quantity in the column of `quantity`, and I choose the quantity 1 or 2 or 3, it post the correct value. But in the second row, when I do the same, it doesn't send the value, just blank. what is wrong with that?

Comment: I'll edited my answer... this was my mistake by not trying how the inputs were submitted

Comment: man, can you help to add one more function with the javascript above. If the quantity is 0, I want to make the checkbox is not able to check. Because we afraid that the user accidentally check the checkbox and it send the empty value, and it will mess the database eventhough there is not big impact for that.

Answer (score 1):

That is a `javascript` answer. Here's the `Jquery` answer: http://jsfiddle.net/n13wbran/5/

You can change the `req` attribute which I assigned myself on checkbox change event:

```
$("input[name^='checkbox']").change(function () {
    var id = this.name.substring(8);
    if (this.checked) {
        $("[name='esquantity" + id + "']").attr("req", "true");
    } else {
        $("[name='esquantity" + id + "']").attr("req", "false");
    }
});
```

Then on `Submit` click, check the lists with `req == "true"` and do the following:

```
$("input[name='Submit']").click(function () {
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i <= parseInt($("[name^='esquantity']").length); i++) {
        if ($("[name='esquantity[" + i + "]']").attr("req") == "true" &&
            $("[name='esquantity[" + i + "]']").val() == "")
            alert("Please select a value for the required lists");
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope. It has been answered. :) I will keep this for studying purpose. :)